# wp-config.php randomly will reset to wp-config-sample.php

Tags: wp-config

It seems every few months my wp-config.php is being overwritten to the wp-config-sample.php. Nothing else is corrupted or changed, just that. It started to do this early 2019. The host is Inmotion. I managed a dozen sites on Siteground and have never seen this issue before. The site in question uses Securi for malware protection and I have enabled files rights to 444 on wp-config.php. Of course it could be a plugin..

Comment: just create a wp-config.php  and leave the wp-config-sample.php stay there

Comment: Currently have both files exist. Are you suggesting that I update the wp-config-sample.php with my settings? I will try that.

Comment: No. Even if you have the wp-config-sample.php wordpress is not going to use it. wordpress only use wp-config.php

Comment: @Enkode that actually may be a decent workaround for the time-being. I would populate `wp-config-sample.php` with the values from `wp-config.php`, that way, in the event that this happens again, your site won't break. I would also ask your host to see if there's been anything fishy going on - WordPress will use `wp-config-sample.php` as the config file if it can't find `wp-config.php`, and will try to load `/wp-admin/setup-config.php` to reconfigure the site (seen near the top of `/wp-load.php`).

Comment: Thanks I took that approach and deleted / re-installed the wp-includes / wp-admin folder as precaution. If it happens again I will run a couple of test sites. 1 with no plugins running and one on a different host to try and isolate the culprit